# using debuild to build my app on Ubuntu: how to find what is causing a specific dependency to appear in ${shlibs:Depends}

Tags: qt, ubuntu, dependencies, qt5

I'm building my Qt 5 app on Ubuntu, either 15.10 or 14.04, using debuild.  I can look at the .substvars file that gets created to see what `${shlibs:Depends}` expands to, and it includes `qtbase-abi-5-4-2`.

How can I find out what is causing that specific dependency?  I'm not a linux guy, but surely there's something that can look at the executable, or something in the output of debuild, and tell me why I have this version-specific dependency?